# how to remove character strip in menu items WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, strip

In my wordpress, a menu item which is just 11 character long is showing like this "FOOD & DRI.." which is FOOD & DRINK original.

How can i change this to normal?

I am editing HADES theme.

[image: a]

Comment: The reason for this is likely to be in the menu code. You'd have to show us that.

Comment: where can i get that?
I am using Hades theme, can you tell me from where i can get the code?
I am new to wordpress :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your menu items have a set width, you can adjust this by editing your CSS for your theme.

**Edit**

The width, height and `...` are being set by the theme files. Will need to edit the theme files for this. Usually is found in functions.php or included files.

Comment: A set width will not add `...` to the menu item, though.

Comment: no, it is not a problem of menu width...

Comment: @Pekka웃 it can in CSS with text-overflow:ellipsis;... It looks like each menu item has a uniform width.

Comment: okay, fair point. That's worth looking into @paz

Comment: Can you check the issue is with CSS? I am unable to find.. :( .. http://gearmale.com/

Comment: @paz we can't do it for you unless you give access to your backend. Maybe give a link to your site.

Comment: the site is gearmale.com

Comment: Ah I see what's happening. The developer created functions for the navigation/menu. You will need to edit the theme files for this to change. See my edit.

Comment: @msbodetti which file i have to change? functions.php?

Comment: It's either in the functions.php or in other included files. You can search for it using a multi search file editor like Text Wrangler

Comment: I am using netbeans, what should i search for, i am getting nothing in functions.php

Comment: You're looking for 'class="banner-back-cus"' or 'class="menu-image-title-"'

Comment: Awesome :) Glad to have helped!